# What's changing the "localhost" in ASP.NET Core connection string?

Tags: mysql, linux, asp.net-core

My asp.net core website talks to mysql using `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.The connection string is set in appsettings.json as:

> "ConnectionStrings": {
>       "DefaultMySqlConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=someuser;Pwd=somepassword;"
>     }

In mysql server, which is deployed on the same ubuntu server with the app, I've added the user `'someuser'@'localhost'`and granted the permissions accordingly.

I'm sharing this server machine with a friend, who already has his own website deployed, including a db on the same mysql server. I didn't think this could cause a problem, until I see in the log that my website is trying to authenticate on the mysql server as user `'someuser'@'myfriendssite.com'`, instead of the expected `'someuser'@'localhost'`.

So at what stage could the `localhost` in connection string be replaced to `myfriendssite.com`? The only place I know and checked is the `/etc/hosts` file, which looks pretty standard:

[image]

And, maybe this will be obvious if the above question is answered: how does one avoid this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's using the `/etc/hostname`, as explained in [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/363122/how-does-mysql-determine-the-hostname-of-its-clients).